# How to stop schedule multiple times and restart if needed. Python. Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, scheduler, schedule

I'm trying to make /stop command for the bot (the greetings stop to send). It works, but only one time, after pressing the /start command it is unable to stop again and runs forever.
Tried different methods of stopping, manged either to stop and unable to restart or to stop once and unable to stop after repeating /start or "greet".
I would be very grateful for the advice of how to improve the existing code

```
    import random, telebot, schedule, time
from telebot import types
from config import token
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

greetings = ["hello", "Have a nice day", "Goodbye", "Wow"]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Greet")
    markup.add(item1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Press button", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def run_function(message):

    def function_to_run():
        random_greet = random.choice(greetings)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random_greet)

    def scheduling():
        schedule.every(4).seconds.do(function_to_run).tag('schedule')
    scheduling()

    if message.text.lower() == "greet":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "here you go")

        function_to_run()

        def schedule_run():
            while True:
                schedule.run_pending()
                time.sleep(1)
        schedule_run()

    elif message.text.lower() == "stop":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "stopping...")
        schedule.clear('schedule')
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "stopped successfully")


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random, telebot, schedule, time
from telebot import types
from config import token
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

greetings = ["hello", "Have a nice day", "Goodbye", "Wow"]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'stop'])
def start_message(message):
    command = message.text.split()[0]
    if command == "/start":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Greet")
        markup.add(item1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Press button", reply_markup=markup)

     elif command == "/stop":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "stopping...")
        schedule.clear('schedule')
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "stopped successfully")
        exit()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def run_function(message):

    ...
    # or 
    elif message.text.lower() == "stop":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "stopping...")
        schedule.clear('schedule')
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "stopped successfully")
        exit()

bot.polling()
```

if you want to on it again try this:

```
import random, telebot, schedule, time
from telebot import types
from config import token
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

greetings = ["hello", "Have a nice day", "Goodbye", "Wow"]
on = True

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'stop'])
def start_message(message):
    global on
    command = message.text.split()[0]
    if command == "/start" and not on: 
        on = True
        # your code

    if command == "/stop" and on: 
        on = False
        # your code

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def run_function(message):
    global on

    if on:
        # your code 

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Please, try to explain your improvements and changes so that the other people can understand and learn from your answer.